# How to use other docker image inside my docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have an application that requires PyTorch library to function, which I've installed on my computer. However, I want to deploy my application and use PyTorch inside a container. To achieve this, I plan to use a pre-built PyTorch Docker image and link it to my container in your Docker Compose file.

In my Docker Compose file, I have included the PyTorch Docker image as a separate service that my application container will depend on. I have also included an environment variable specifying the path where PyTorch is installed inside the PyTorch container. Finally, I have mounted the source code and data directories as volumes in the application container, so that the application code can access them :

```
version: '3'
services:
  myapp:
    build: .
    image: myapp:latest
    environment:
      - PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app/src
      - ./data:/app/data
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - pytorch

  pytorch:
    image: pytorch/pytorch:latest
```

I am getting this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'

As I understand "depends on" will not make my app use the PyTorch docker image.
Important: I don't want to make a docker container or image on top of PyTorch docker. I need to make my docker container use PyTorch image

Comment: If you have separate containers, you need to use a network interface like an HTTP call or a RabbitMQ queue to communicate between them.  You might need to build your custom image `FROM pytorch/pytorch`, or install the library a different way.

Comment: @DavidMaze I remember I have used tensorflow docker and linked it to my Jupyter notebook docker container. I didn't used any mq, just docker. But I don't remember how I did it